# Remotely change permissions of a UNIX file using chmod ant task within WebSphere MQ FTE?

Tags: unix, ant, chmod, websphere-mq-fte

I am currently working with `WebSphere MQ FTE`.

Let us consider the below scenario :

`A` is a unix server and there is a file in `/test/file.txt`

The file permission for this file is `-rw-r--r--.`

I want to change the permission of this file to -rw-rw-rw using an `ant` script (chmod task) which I should invoke from a server `B`(windows).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this as a WMQ FTE task you would use a [Managed Call](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/call.htm) if the entire task was to change the permissions, or you would use a [pre- or post-transfer call](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/transfer_message_format.htm) if you needed to change the permissions either before or after the transfer.

The call or task could directly execute chmod but that would require the sandbox to include a directory containing many potentially dangerous commands.  It would be better to make a script that invoked chmod or a link to chmod and put the script or link in a dedicated bin directory sandboxed for the FTE agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sshexec task:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html

Answer (score 0):

Post destination you can execute below ant command..

```
<chmod file="${source_path}/${destination.filename}" perm="664"/>
```